# UITableView Showing last value of a loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, loops

I would like to show all the values of this loop in the tableview. The code is to calculate an Amortization Table for loans. I tried saving the data of the loop in the array, but it always gives me the last values. I really got stuck on this. So how can I do that, please? This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class tableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var arr = [Int]()
var cell:tableCell!
var TPayment: float_t! // calls value of 59600 from main controller
var years1: float_t! // number of months = 180 ( 15 years)
var monthlyPayment: float_t! // 471
var interest: float_t! // 5%
var principil: float_t! //222
var interestrate: float_t! // 249
var initil: float_t!
var data = Array<float_t>()
var data2: NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self

    tableView.dataSource = self

    let c = Int(years1)
    arr += 0...c

    tableCalculation()

        // Register custom cell
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "table", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

func tableCalculation() {
    let years = Int(years1)
    initil = TPayment - 0

    for i in 0..<years {
            initil = initil - principil
            interest = initil * interestrate                
            principil = monthlyPayment - interest                
            print("Month : \(monthlyPayment),   principil: \(principil),interest: \(interest), initi: \(initil)")
            data = [interest]
            self.data2 = [initil]
    }        
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! tableCell
    cell.lbl1.text = "\(arr[indexPath.row])"        
    cell.lbl2.text =  "\(monthlyPayment)"
    cell.lbl3.text = "\(data[indexPath.row % data.count])"
    cell.lbl4.text = "\(principal)"
    cell.lbl5.text = "\(self.data2[indexPath.section])"        
    return cell        
}    

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
}
```

[Table View with UITableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoYiv.png)

[Table view with print()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcOLE.png)

Comment: Post only the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: I did before and no body understood it, so putting the full code will help to understand the whole point of my question.

Comment: I don't understand your question and it's not useful to future users who may be having the same issue. You're not specific about what problem you're having. Only the necessary code should be posted and the mathematical/coding problems you're having. Hopefully someone else understands if not. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask @yousefalenezi

Comment: I already attached 2 Photos with the code: @Pyro

Table View with UITableView

Table view with print()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is with your data array.

In your loop where you populate your data array, in `tableCalculation`, there's this:

```
data = [interest]
```

It means that for each iteration you *set* the data array to `[interest]` instead of *appending* the new item to the array.

What you should do instead:

```
data.append(interest)
```

Note that you make the same mistake with `self.data2`. But now you know how to fix this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you are giving the same data to print that looks like the issue

I don't get much for all the labels but you can change it based on the requirement

for lbl2 and lbl4 you are passing a same single float variable for all the rows that's why it show the same value, if you want to show the different value for each row you should store it in array and at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` get it like you are doing for lbl1

```
cell.lbl2.text =  currencyFormatter(monthlyPayment)
cell.lbl4.text = currencyFormatter(principil)
```

for lbl5 Your code cell code should be like this

```
cell.lbl5.text = "\(self.data2[indexPath.row])"
```

For the lbl 3 & lbl 5 when i execute this code with static value to get interest it only stores one value in the array

```
for i in 0..<years {
   let interest = 5.0 * 4.0
    data = [interest]
}
```

to store every value you calculated in array you should use `append`

```
data.append(interest)
self.data2.append(initil)
```

as there is only 1 value in the array for every index path it gives 0th value in the array as per your modulo operation so it shows same value in each row

Comment: i am glad, that helps