# Get data from Attribute and save in array

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, uiimage

I want to catch the data from CoreData and then save it in an array of images. So it´s get all images when it´s run but in the array are always the last image and i need all images in the array. Whats are my Problem here in the Code ??

Thanks for your Help :)

```
var playImages: [UIImage] = []


 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EveryPicture")

    do {
        let result = try mgdContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        if let objects = result as? [EveryPicture] {
            for foto in objects {

                let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: foto.everyfoto!)
                print("\(image)")

                playImages = [image!]

            }

        }


    }catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    print("\(playImages)array")
```

Comment: The problem is in playImages = [image] you overwrite always the array with the latest value

Comment: oke and how can i make right in this Code ?

Comment: Similar issue solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36249883/2227743

Comment: You're welcome. :) I've closed the question as a duplicate so other users can find the solution too.